# How to get uncompressed css output while using LESS(less-watch-compiler.js)?

Tags: css, less

I have started using less and find it great but one thing which i don't like is that the output css is compressed/minified - whole output is packed in just one line, while i need an uncompressed css output?

I am using Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler-master.js to watch my Less directory and any change i in my less file is compiled into css file.

in my project directory i write command

> node less-watch-compiler.js less_di css_dir

Comment: How exactly are you processing your .less file in the first place?

Comment: That particular script explicitly causes lessc to minify the result. Regular lessc doesn't do that by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Less from the command-line via `lessc` then the default output should be unminified.
If you want to minimize the output you'll have to pass an extra parameter, `-x`, see [the Less homepage](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage) for more details.

If Less is built into your workflow somehow differently you'll need to check for additionally passed parameters.

---

The script you're referencing includes the parameter, [in the function `compileCSS`, line 147](https://github.com/jonycheung/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler/blob/master/less-watch-compiler.js):

```
var command = 'lessc -x '+file.replace(/\s+/g,'\\ ')+' '+argvs[1]+'/'+filename.replace(/\s+/g,'\\ ')+'.css';
```

You can either manually remove the `-x` from the command to receive unminified output or edit the script to accept an additional parameter (and then preferably make a pull request to the script author/maintainer).

Comment: I am using Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler-master.js to watch less changes to css